# Xampp on Mac: PHP intl installation error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found' ERROR: `make' failed

Tags: php, macos, xampp, intl

I'm trying [this tutorial](https://newbedev.com/php-intl-installation-on-xampp) to get the extension installed, but when I try this command: sudo pecl install intl, and got this output:

```
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ubrk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

After looking things up online, I found that I need icu4c installed. I already had, but reinstalled it with brew reinstall icu4c, but I still get the error, what should I do?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue. BTW which version of php you are trying with? I am having issue with php 8.1.

Comment: No I actually didn't find one. I just decided to leave it for a while, and found that later I didn't need to install intl. Also worth mentioning I had an Intel Mac when I posted this, and I now have the M1 Pro MBP.

Comment: If anyone still looking for answer of this question, no direct solution found however I removed and reinstall a previous version 7.x of xampp and install other packages according to that version.